# Bootbox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I am trying to create a modal using Bootbox. I have the modal popup and ask you to fill in some data. I am then trying to do validation so when they click on save, it checks to just make sure the fields are filled in.

How can I prevent the modal from closing when clicking save if validation fails?

```
bootbox.dialog(header + content, [{
    "label": "Save",
    "class": "btn-primary",
    "callback": function() {

        title = $("#title").val();
        description = $("#description").val();
        icon = $("#icon").val();
        href = $("#link").val();
        newWindow = $("#newWindow").val();
        type = $("#type").val();
        group = $("#group").val();

            if (!title){ $("#titleDiv").attr('class', 'control-group error'); } else {
                addMenu(title, description, icon, href, newWindow, type, group);
            }
    }
}, {
    "label": "Cancel",
    "class": "btn",
    "callback": function() {}
}]);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can just return false in your "Save" button callback

like this:

```
bootbox.dialog(header + content, [{
    "label": "Save",
    "class": "btn-primary",
    "callback": function() {

        title = $("#title").val();
        description = $("#description").val();
        icon = $("#icon").val();
        href = $("#link").val();
        newWindow = $("#newWindow").val();
        type = $("#type").val();
        group = $("#group").val();

            if (!title){ 
                $("#titleDiv").attr('class', 'control-group error'); 
                return false; 
            } else {
                addMenu(title, description, icon, href, newWindow, type, group);
            }
    }
}, {
    "label": "Cancel",
    "class": "btn",
    "callback": function() {}
}]);
```

Comment: But It doesn't close the model by clicking in "Cancel" button if callback returns false. Kindly give your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @AjeetMalviya, the solution posted by @bruchowski does not close the Bootbox when using `return false;` that way. The callback returns `null` when the Cancel button is clicked and an empty string when the OK button is clicked.

```
<script>
    var bb = bootbox.prompt({
        title: 'Input Required',
        onEscape: true,
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: '<svg><use xlink:href="/icons.svg#check" /></svg> OK'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: '<svg><use xlink:href="/icons.svg#x" /></svg> Cancel',
                className: 'btn-secondary'
            }
        },
        inputType: 'password',
        callback: function (result) {
            //result is null when Cancel is clicked
            //empty when OK is clicked
            if (result === null) {
                return;
            } else if (result === '') {
                bb.find('.bootbox-input-password').addClass('input-validation-error');
                return false;
            }

            console.log(result);
        }
    });

    bb.init(function () {
        //do stuff with the bootbox on startup here
    });
</script>
```